# Clamping a vector to a minimum and maximum?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, clamp

I came accross this:
t = Clamp(t/d, 0, 1)
 but I'm not sure how to perform this operation on a vector. What are the steps to clamp a vector if one was writing their own vector implementation?

Thanks

clamp       clamping a vector to a minimum and a maximum

ex:

```
pc = # the point you are coloring now
p0 = # start point
p1 = # end point
v = p1 - p0
d = Length(v)
v = Normalize(v) # or Scale(v, 1/d)

v0 = pc - p0

t = Dot(v0, v)
t = Clamp(t/d, 0, 1)

color = (start_color * t) + (end_color * (1 - t))
```

Comment: Explain further what the function should do.

Comment: What do you mean by clamping a vector? Clamping each entry of the vector? Clamping the vector itself to a sphere in R^n?

Comment: Clamping a vector to a minimum and a maximum

Comment: @user146780: Maximum and minimum **what**? Number of elements? Value of all elements contained whithin? Memory allocated?

Comment: t and d are both scalars here. Why do you need to clamp a vector? Just use the code Chris posted below, on the scalar t/d with lb = 0 and ub = 1.

Comment: @user146780: That's not even clamping a vector, that's clamping t, right? Notice that t and d are both scalars, so that presumably just means "clamp" t within the range 0 to 1.

Comment: Now that I know its a scalar it makes more sense

Comment: I hope you would have known... `d` is the return from `Length()` - lengths are clearly scalars, and `t` is the result of `Dot()`, which sounds like a dot product, which is also a scalar. Time to read up on dot products, maybe? Or take a break?

Comment: Note that this is about math vectors, not C++ vectors. It looks like he wants to change a property (the color) of a point `pc` according to how far it lies along the line between `p0` and `p1`. For points outside the range between p0 and p1, the property should be bounded ("Clamped") to the nearest point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
clamp(vec, lb, ub) == min(max(vec, lb), ub)
```

**edit**

min and max are usually primitive operations on vectors.  For example, if you're using SSE vectors, there are **_mm_min_ps** and **_mm_max_ps** intrinsics that turn into **MINPS** and **MAXPS** instructions on x86.

Comment: What are the min and max functions?

Comment: @user146780: That's what everyone's asking you in the comments to your question!

Comment: min and max are defined in the c++ library in <algorithm>

Comment: And they assume `bool operator<(T, T)` exists. Typically they don't exist for a vector. Is (-1,0,0) < (0.5,0,0) ?

Answer (score 5):

I think that once you state clearly what you mean you'll find that most of the work is done for you...

I'm guessing you want to limit the *length* of the vector quantity (rather than a vector data structure) to lie within a specified range without changing its direction, no?

So:

```
if (v.length > max)
   v.setlength(max)
else if (v.length < min)
   v. setlength(min)
```

where the implementation of `length()` and `setlength()` depend on how you have stored your vector.

---

If your vector is stored in (angle,magnitude) form this is nearly trivial. If stored in Cartesian form (ie. (x,y,z) ) you get `length` from the Pythagorian theorem and `setlength` should scale each commponent by a factor of `desired_length/current_length`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is when you consider a vector in a spherical coordinate system: {R, φ, θ}. φ and θ are already limited to [-π,+π] and [-½π, +½π] anyway. Hence, you only need to clamp the distance from the origin R.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I'd assuming you'd want to clamp each of the coordinates individually. So...

```
void clamp(const Vector3 &v, const Vector3 &min, const Vector3 &max)
{
    v.x = clamp(v.x, min.x, max.x);
    v.y = clamp(v.y, min.y, max.y);
    v.z = clamp(v.z, min.z, max.z);
}

int clamp(int value, int min, int max)
{
    if (value < min)
    {
        return min;
    }
    else if (value > max)
    {
        return max;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Clamping coordinates independently may change the direction of the vector, which is not how I interpreted the request.

Comment: I was thinking of a vector in the context of 3d graphics. A clamp function could be useful there in ensuring a point remains within a cube. I didn't really know what he was asking.

Comment: Even if you wanted to make sure that the vector remains in a cube (or a sphere) there's still the question whether you want to keep the direction.